# How can I make Apache rewrite not break an image?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, webserver

I have a very simple html page sitting at example.com. It consists solely of the following `index.html`:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:black;">
<img src="images/picture1.jpg" alt="example" style="width:40%;">
</html>
```

The page loads exactly as expected when I go to example.com, but I wanted to make it so any requests to example.com are redirected to this front page (so example.com/catfood takes a user to example.com). I added the following to `.htaccess` for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301]
```

It redirects correctly, but it breaks the image. I believe this is happening because the request to example.com/images/picture1.jpg is now being redirected to the index page, but I'm not sure what I need to add to my .htaccess to allow the blanket redirection to happen while still loading this image on the front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another RewriteCond saying that the rule only applies if the request doesn't point to an existing file.

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

So:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301]
```

See
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html